# Get ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Key name along with values

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

```
string[] Accounts = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
                        .Where(key => key.StartsWith("Account"))
                        .Select(key => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key])
                        .ToArray();
```

Here I'm getting all the `AppSettings` that starts with `Account` but currently they only return the value of the object.

Is there a way I can turn `string[] Accounts` into `List<Tuple<String, String>> Accounts` so it would be like `List<Tuple<key, value>> Accounts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely - all you need to do is changing your `Select` to return the desired tuple, and calling `ToList` in place of `ToArray`:

```
List<Tuple<String,String>> Accounts = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
    .Where(key => key.StartsWith("Account"))
    .Select(key => Tuple.Create(key, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks alot, didnt knew it was that easy :D